# .xls file not detected java

Tags: java, xls

When I try to load the xls file it doesn't work even though is in the same folder. I also tried it with absolute paths.
(It all happened because of missing jars, here is the list with all of them. To solve the issue of relative paths the url.getResource() from below works fine.)
[My Jar List(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxFrs.png)

```
public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("MP.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook l = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
        }
        
    }
 public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\alumno.Alumno-PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\pruebas xlsx\\src\\pruebasxlsx\\MP.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook l = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
        }
        
    }
```

[This is where the file is located(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q76de.png)

This is the error with relative path:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: MP.xls (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
at pruebasxlsx.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

this is the error with an absolute path

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.setSize(RootProperty.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.DirectoryProperty.<init>(DirectoryProperty.java:52)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.<init>(RootProperty.java:31)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.PropertyTable.<init>(PropertyTable.java:58)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:99)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:272)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:399)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:381)
    at pruebasxlsx.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please try like this, FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("*file_path\\MP.xls"));

Comment: With the relative path the same error pops up, with the absolute path it gives another one. but still not working

Comment: Can you please add both ways that you tried and related errors that were found?

Comment: The absolute path was what? You can try it by doing the following in cmd.exe: `dir C:\Users\foo\bar\MP.xlx`

Comment: Give file extension .xlsx instead of  .xls it will work

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileInputStream with the absolute path works. Just the reading with HSSFWorkbook- misses a library.

The relative path is a volatile option. If the file is a read-only source, bundle it with the application, and do not use a File (file system file), but use a resource, a "file" on the class path, possibly bundled in an application jar.

```
   InputStream f = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/pruebasxslx/MP.xls");
   HSSFWorkbook l = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
```

For HSSFWorkbook a library with `org.apache.commons.math3` classes is not found,
an indirect needed library.

As these library dependencies are extra work, already done by others, and involving moving coherent versions of all libraries to work together, one should better use for instance **maven**, a build infrastructure. Maven (or gradle) projects are supported by most IDEs, and have a bit different directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

File input stream gets the file named by the path name in the file system - that means an absolute path, as parameter, not relative path.

If you want to load a file from the location of your class use:

```
URL url = class.getResource("file.txt");
```

and then get absolute path of it by using:

```
url.getPath();
```

So, below solution should work (it can be polished but you will get an idea):

```
public class Main {
   static URL url = Main.class.getResource("MP.xls");

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
       FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(url.getPath());
       HSSFWorkbook l = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't find the file.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Comment: Are you sure that your filename is MP.xls and its located in same directory as your class?

Comment: Yes, i also tried different file locations, such as desktop etc,